# How can I grep through all files #included in the file currently open in vim?

Tags: c++, vim

Suppose I have the following `.hpp` file open in `vim`:

```
#pragma once
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"
#include "c.hpp"

#include <boost/something.hpp>
// some code
```

Now, let's say I want to search for any occurrence of the term `Token` in any of the included files (possibly in the files *they* include as well). How can I do this easily?

I would like to skip over any files not locatable from my current `vimpath`, e.g. in this case I might not have `boost` in my path so I would want it to simply not search in `boost/something.hpp`.

Comment: Would you like to search in STD for `Token`, too?

Comment: @NaCl only if it's in the path, e.g. if I can `gf` the file then it should search through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [include-search](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#include-search) functionality available in vim. In particular, this is the command required to search for all occurrences of `Token` when you have the cursor over that word:

```
[I          Display all lines that contain the keyword under the
            cursor.  Filenames and line numbers are displayed
            for the found lines.  The search starts at the
            beginning of the file.  {not in Vi}
```

To jump to the first occurrence you can use:

```
[<Tab>
```

Taken from Bram's presentation [Seven habits of effective editing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX9m3g5J-XA) at time 26'08".

This last command is also described in Vim's help as following:

```
[ CTRL-I    Jump to the first line that contains the keyword
            under the cursor.  The search starts at the beginning
            of the file.  Lines that look like a comment are
            ignored (see 'comments' option).  If a count is given,
            the count'th matching line is jumped to, and comment
            lines are not ignored.  {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 0):

See `:help include-search` for several methods to automatically search included files in Vim. For simple token searches, `[i` is probably the easiest solution. If you need a full regular expression, or if you don't have the token somewhere to put your cursor over it, you can use the `:isearch` command.